# Binary Time Series Forecasting

Tags: time-series

I am working with daily binary time series forecast as follows:

- The target : purchase decision (0: not purchase, 1 purchase
- Features: day, weekday, promotion, holiday,....

The objective is trying to forecast that the day have purchase or not!
So, What algorithms can be used to address this problem!
I also research about markov chain  , Survival analysis.. but i am not sure it can be applied?

Comment: We will need details on: size of dataset, what features you have, etc

Comment: What makes this a time series? Is it the same person making the purchase decision each time? Then that is a time series. Is it a different person making the purchase decision each time? That is not a time series.

Answer (score 0):

Although the nature of your data might present a time-series format, it looks like you can frame it as a usual classifier, building a tabular dataset based on the features you point out, something like:

| day | weekday | promotion | holiday | purchase_target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Monday | 0.5 | True | 0 |
| 2 | Tuesday | 0.3 | False | 0 |
| 3 | Wednesday | 0 | False | 1 |

You can begin with simple binary classifiers, like [naive bayes](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.naive_bayes) classifier, [logistic regressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression)... and aslso have a look at a comparisson of some others [in this link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html).

Comment: Thanks you! I also conduct this method. But the accuracy is not good! Any approach please suggest me!

Comment: this method does not guarantee accuracy by itself; you could add some feature engineering trying to add new explainable features, but first, make sure your dataset  is realiable and you build a baseline model to have a reference